# Why do we have to tell printf() the type of data in C?

Tags: c, io, type-safety

Let's consider this C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  int x=5;
  printf("x is ");
  printf("%d",5);
}
```

In this, when we wrote `int x=5;` we told the computer that `x` is an integer. The computer must remember that `x` is an integer. But when we output the value of `x` in `printf()` we have to again tell the computer that `x` is an integer. Why is that?

Why does the computer forget that `x` was an integer?

Comment: The compiler knows that x is an integer, but printf does not.

Comment: it's just how the calling convention works, there is only 1 implementation of `printf(char*, ...)` and it just gets (what amounts to) a pointer to a collection of data

Comment: @ratchetfreak Why is it so? Why printf doesn't get the pointer of data type automatically as it is in C++ where "cout" function automatically knows the data type?

Comment: @user31782 the `cout << a << b;` translates to `cout.print(a).print(b);` which has the advantage of templates which C doesn't have and overloading (also missing from C)

Comment: @ratchetfreak ok, so there is some basic problem with the language itself, it lacks some features?

Comment: Have you considered `printf("x is %x in hex, and %d in decimal and %o as octal",x,x,x);`?

Comment: @MichaelT No I haven't. I thought %d is for specifiying integers(perhaps the binary number is taken as int by the conputer by default!?). I think I need to study it more. I'll try to print it in hexadecimal and octa.

Comment: @MichaelT I am not getting the hexadecimal and octadecimal values. The out I get is: `x is 5, and 5 in decimal and 5 as octal`. I'm using portable Dev-C++ having  "MinGW GCC 4.6.2 32-bit as its compiler".

Comment: Try it with the number 163. Values less than 8 are rather uninteresting in this situation. Or better yet, loop from 0 to 255 and see what the numbers are. The point is that there is more in printf than just they type.

Comment: @MichaelT It works now.

Comment: @user31782 side bit, I once had a program that did `sprint(fmt,"%%%dd",width); printf(fmt,number);` of something to that effect.  In that case, I didn't know what the maximum length of the number was before I ran the program but wanted the numbers to line up nicely without any unnecessary space padding.  You don't know what the string fmt *could* be until runtime.

Comment: printf only needs to know when you want to format it.. otherwise it doesn't care

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are two issues at play here:

Issue #1: C is a *statically typed* language; all type information is determined at compile time.  No type information is stored with any object in memory such that its type and size can be determined at run time<sup>1</sup>.  If you examine the memory at any particular address while the program is running, all you'll see is a sludge of bytes; there's nothing to tell you whether that particular address actually contains an object, what the type or size of that object is, or how to interpret those bytes (as an integer, or floating point type, or sequence of characters in a string, etc.).  All that information is baked into the machine code when the code is compiled, based on type information specified in the source code; for example, the function definition

```
void foo( int x, double y, char *z )
{
  ...
}
```

tells the compiler to generate the appropriate machine code to handle `x` as an integer, `y` as a floating-point value, and `z` as a pointer to `char`.  Note that any mismatches in the number or type of arguments between a function call and a function definition are only detected when the code is being compiled<sup>2</sup>; it's only during the compilation phase that any type information is associated with an object.

Issue #2: `printf` is a *variadic* function; it takes one fixed parameter of type `const char * restrict` (the format string), along with zero or more additional parameters, the number and type of which are *not* known at compile time:

```
int printf( const char * restrict fmt, ... );
```

The `printf` function has no way of knowing what the number and types of additional arguments are from the passed arguments themselves; it has to rely on the format string to tell it how to interpret the sludge of bytes on the stack (or in the registers).  Even better, because it's a variadic function, arguments with certain types are *promoted* to a limited set of default types (e.g., `short` is promoted to `int`, `float` is promoted to `double`, etc.).

Again, there's no information associated with the additional arguments themselves to give `printf` any clues on how to interpret or format them.  Hence the need for the conversion specifiers in the format string.

Note that in addition to telling `printf` the number and type of additional arguments, conversion specifiers also tell `printf` how to *format* the output (field widths, precision, padding, justification, base (decimal, octal, or hex for integer types), etc.).

**Edit**

To avoid extensive discussion in the comments (and because the chat page is blocked from my work system - yes I'm being a bad boy), I'm going to address the last two questions here.

> IF I do this:
>
> ```
> float b;          
> float c;           
> b=3.1;    
> c=(5.0/9.0)*(b);
> ```
>
> In the last statement how does the compiler know that b is of type float?

During translation, the compiler maintains a table (often called a *symbol table*) that stores information about an object's name, type, storage duration, scope, etc.  You *declared* `b` and `c` as `float`, so any time the compiler sees an expression with `b` or `c` in it, it will generate the machine code to handle a floating-point value.

I took your code above and wrapped a full program around it:

```
/**
 * c1.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
  float b;
  float c;
  b = 3.1;
  c = (5.0 / 9.0) * b;

  printf( "c = %f\n", c );
  return 0;
}
```

I used the `-g` and `-Wa,-aldh` options with gcc to create a listing of the generated machine code interleaved with the C source code<sup>3</sup>:

```
GAS LISTING /tmp/ccmGgGG2.s                     page 1

   1                            .file   "c1.c"
   9                    .Ltext0:
  10                            .section        .rodata
  11                    .LC2:
  12 0000 63203D20              .string "c = %f\n"
  12      25660A00
  13                            .align 8
  14                    .LC1:
  15 0008 721CC771              .long   1908874354
  16 000c 1CC7E13F              .long   1071761180
  17                            .text
  18                    .globl main
  20                    main:
  21                    .LFB2:
  22                            .file 1 "c1.c"
   1:c1.c          **** #include <stdio.h>
   2:c1.c          **** int main( void )
   3:c1.c          **** {
  23                            .loc 1 3 0
  24 0000 55                    pushq   %rbp
  25                    .LCFI0:
  26 0001 4889E5                movq    %rsp, %rbp
  27                    .LCFI1:
  28 0004 4883EC10              subq    $16, %rsp
  29                    .LCFI2:
   4:c1.c          ****   float b;
   5:c1.c          ****   float c;
   6:c1.c          ****   b = 3.1;
  30                            .loc 1 6 0
  31 0008 B8666646              movl    $0x40466666, %eax
  31      40
  32 000d 8945F8                movl    %eax, -8(%rbp)
   7:c1.c          ****   c = (5.0 / 9.0) * b;
  33                            .loc 1 7 0
  34 0010 F30F5A4D              cvtss2sd        -8(%rbp), %xmm1
  34      F8
  35 0015 F20F1005              movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0
  35      00000000
  36 001d F20F59C1              mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0
  37 0021 F20F5AC0              cvtsd2ss        %xmm0, %xmm0
  38 0025 F30F1145              movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)
  38      FC
   8:c1.c          ****
   9:c1.c          ****   printf( "c = %f\n", c );
  39                            .loc 1 9 0
  40 002a F30F5A45              cvtss2sd        -4(%rbp), %xmm0
  40      FC
  41 002f BF000000              movl    $.LC2, %edi
  41      00
  42 0034 B8010000              movl    $1, %eax
  42      00
  43 0039 E8000000              call    printf
  43      00
  10:c1.c          ****   return 0;
  44                            .loc 1 10 0
  45 003e B8000000              movl    $0, %eax

GAS LISTING /tmp/ccmGgGG2.s                     page 2

  11:c1.c          **** }
  46                            .loc 1 11 0
  47 0043 C9                    leave
  48 0044 C3                    ret
```

Here's how to read the assembly listing:

```
  40 002a F30F5A45              cvtss2sd        -4(%rbp), %xmm0
  40      FC
  ^  ^    ^                     ^               ^
  |  |    |                     |               |
  |  |    |                     |               +-- Instruction operands
  |  |    |                     +------------------ Instruction mnemonic
  |  |    +---------------------------------------- Actual machine code (instruction and operands)
  |  +--------------------------------------------- Byte offset of instruction from subroutine entry point
  +------------------------------------------------ Line number of assembly listing
```

One thing to note here.  In the generated assembly code, there are no symbols for `b` or `c`; they only exist in the source code listing.  When `main` executes at runtime, space for `b` and `c` (along with some other stuff) is allocated from the stack by adjusting the stack pointer:

```
subq    $16, %rsp
```

The code refers to those objects by their offset from the frame pointer<sup>4</sup>, with `b` being -8 bytes from the address stored in the frame pointer and `c` being -4 bytes from it, as follows:

```
   7:c1.c          ****   c = (5.0 / 9.0) * b;
  .loc 1 7 0
  cvtss2sd        -8(%rbp), %xmm1  ;; converts contents of b from single- to double-
                                   ;; precision float, stores result to floating-
                                   ;; point register xmm1
  movsd   .LC1(%rip), %xmm0        ;; writes the pre-computed value of 5.0/9.0  
                                   ;; to floating point register xmm0
  mulsd   %xmm1, %xmm0             ;; multiply contents of xmm1 by xmm0, store result
                                   ;; in xmm0
  cvtsd2ss        %xmm0, %xmm0     ;; convert result in xmm0 from double- to single-
                                   ;; precision float
  movss   %xmm0, -4(%rbp)          ;; save result to c
```

Since you declared `b` and `c` as floats, the compiler generated machine code to specifically handle floating-point values; the `movsd`, `mulsd`, `cvtss2sd` instructions are all specific to floating-point operations, and the registers `%xmm0` and `%xmm1` are used to store double-precision floating point values.

If I change the source code so that `b` and `c` are integers instead of floats, the compiler generates different machine code:

```
/**
 * c2.c
 */
#include <stdio.h>
int main( void )
{
  int b;
  int c;
  b = 3;
  c = (9 / 4) * b; // changed these values since integer 5/9 == 0, making for
                   // some really boring machine code.

  printf( "c = %d\n", c );
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -o c2 -g -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wa,-aldh=c2.lst c2.c` gives:

```
GAS LISTING /tmp/ccyxHwid.s                     page 1

   1                            .file   "c2.c"
   9                    .Ltext0:
  10                            .section        .rodata
  11                    .LC0:
  12 0000 63203D20              .string "c = %d\n"
  12      25640A00
  13                            .text
  14                    .globl main
  16                    main:
  17                    .LFB2:
  18                            .file 1 "c2.c"
   1:c2.c          **** #include <stdio.h>
   2:c2.c          **** int main( void )
   3:c2.c          **** {
  19                            .loc 1 3 0
  20 0000 55                    pushq   %rbp
  21                    .LCFI0:
  22 0001 4889E5                movq    %rsp, %rbp
  23                    .LCFI1:
  24 0004 4883EC10              subq    $16, %rsp
  25                    .LCFI2:
   4:c2.c          ****   int b;
   5:c2.c          ****   int c;
   6:c2.c          ****   b = 3;
  26                            .loc 1 6 0
  27 0008 C745F803              movl    $3, -8(%rbp)
  27      000000
   7:c2.c          ****   c = (9 / 4) * b;
  28                            .loc 1 7 0
  29 000f 8B45F8                movl    -8(%rbp), %eax
  30 0012 01C0                  addl    %eax, %eax
  31 0014 8945FC                movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
   8:c2.c          ****
   9:c2.c          ****   printf( "c = %d\n", c );
  32                            .loc 1 9 0
  33 0017 8B75FC                movl    -4(%rbp), %esi
  34 001a BF000000              movl    $.LC0, %edi
  34      00
  35 001f B8000000              movl    $0, %eax
  35      00
  36 0024 E8000000              call    printf
  36      00
  10:c2.c          ****   return 0;
  37                            .loc 1 10 0
  38 0029 B8000000              movl    $0, %eax
  38      00
  11:c2.c          **** }
  39                            .loc 1 11 0
  40 002e C9                    leave
  41 002f C3                    ret
```

Here's the same operation, but with `b` and `c` declared as integers:

```
   7:c2.c          ****   c = (9 / 4) * b;
  .loc 1 7 0
  movl    -8(%rbp), %eax  ;; copy value of b to register eax
  addl    %eax, %eax      ;; since 9/4 == 2 (integer arithmetic), double the
                          ;; value in eax
  movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)  ;; write result to c
```

This is what I meant earlier when I said that type information was "baked in" to the machine code.  When the program runs, it doesn't examine `b` or `c` to determine their type; it already knows what their type *should be* based on the generated machine code.

> If the compiler determines the type and size at run time then why doesn't the following program works:
>
> ```
> float b='H';         
> printf(" value of b is %c \n",b);
> ```

It doesn't work because you're lying to the compiler. You tell it that `b` is a `float`, so it will generate machine code to handle floating-point values. When you initialize it, the bit pattern corresponding to the constant `'H'` will be interpreted as a floating-point value, not a character value.

You lie to the compiler again when you use the `%c` conversion specifier, which expects a value of type `char`, for the argument `b`. Because of this, `printf` won't interpret the contents of `b` correctly, and you'll wind up with garbage output<sup>5</sup>.  Again, `printf` can't know the number or types of any additional arguments based on the arguments themselves; all it sees is an address on the stack (or a bunch of registers).  It needs the format string to tell it what additional arguments have been passed, and what their types are.

---

<sup>1.  The one exception being variable-length arrays; since their size isn't established until runtime, there's no way to evaluate `sizeof` on a VLA at compile time.


2.  As of C89, anyway. Prior to that, the compiler could only catch mismatches in the function return type; it couldn't detect mismatches in the function parameter lists.



3.  This code is generated on a 64-bit SuSE Linux Enterprise 10 system using gcc 4.1.2. If you're on a different implementation (compiler/OS/chip architecture), then the exact machine instructions will be different, but the general point will still hold; the compiler will generate different instructions to handle floats vs. ints vs. strings, etc.



4.  When you call a function in a running program, a *stack frame* is created to store the function arguments, local variables, and the address of the instruction following the function call.  A special register called the *frame pointer* is used to keep track of the current frame. 



5.  For example, assume a big-endian system where the high-order byte is the addressed byte.  The bit pattern for `H` will be stored to `b` as `0x00000048`.  However, because the `%c` conversion specifier indicates that the argument should be a `char`, only the first byte will be read, so `printf` will try to write the character corresponding to the encoding `0x00`.</sup>

Comment: If C is a statically typed language, then how does putchar() prints the correct data type without mentioning it the type?

Comment: @user31782: The definition of the `putchar` function says that it expects 1 argument of type `int`; when the compiler generates the machine code, that machine code will assume that it always receives that single integer argument.  There's no need to specify the type at runtime.

Comment: I can print alphabets using putchar().

Comment: @user31782: Yes, because that's what `putchar` *does* - it prints characters from the execution character set to standard output based on the value passed to it.  For example, if the execution character set is ASCII and you pass an integer value of 65, `putchar` will write the character `'A'` to standard output, since 65 is the ASCII code for `'A'`. `putchar(65);` and `putchar('A');` yield the same output, because the value of the *character constant* 'A' is 65 (assuming ASCII).

Comment: Why doesn't printf() converts thing into ASCII? This way we won't need format specifier. I guess I can make a function Adprintf() which dont need format specifier.

Comment: @user31782: `printf` formats all its output as text (ASCII or otherwise); the conversion specifier tells it how to format the output.  `printf( "%d\n", 65 );` will write the *sequence of characters* `'6'` and `'5'` to standard output, because the `%d` conversion specifier tells it to format the corresponding argument as a decimal integer.  `printf( "%c\n", 65 );` will write the character `'A'` to standard output, because `%c` tells `printf` to format the argument as a character from the execution character set.

Comment: IF I do this: `float b;
        float c;
        b=3.1;    c=(5.0/9.0)*(b); `  In the last statement how does the compiler know that `b` is of type float?

Comment: If the compiler determines the type and size at run time then why doesn't the following program works: `float b='H';
 
 printf(" value of b is %c \n",b);`

Comment: @user31782: see my edit.

Comment: Assembly language is too much for me. As I understand now, the thing is that the compiler calculates the value of `c` before hand. But When the compiler sees `c` in printf() then why doesn't it calculate it as float and make such a machine code that could print it as float. Can't it automatically set the format specifier for itself; it knows that `c` in printf() is of type float.

Comment: What I want to say is that in the compilation phase the compiler knows the type of data even when it sees `c` in printf(). Then why doesn't it write the format specifier by itself? E.g. the code should have been `printf(c);`. The compiler reads it and notice that `c` is of type float and then it modifies the code to `printf("%f",c);`.

Comment: @user31782: What if you want to display the value as hex?  Octal?  What if you want the field width to be 10 characters wide with leading 0s?  What if you only want to display 2 decimal places for floats?  What if you want to display 21 decimal places?  What if you want strings to be no wider than 20 characters?  This is why the compiler doesn't fill in the format string for you, because you're the one who knows how you want your output formatted.  It would be nice to just have a generic placeholder that didn't care about type, but C just doesn't work that way.

Comment: I agree that there are a lot of advantages of `printf()`. What I want to say is that in C language we can make something equivalent to the `cout` of C++.

Comment: @user31782: Not without a change to the language definition.  Sure, it's *possible* (C++ is also statically typed, but is able to infer types for the `<<` and `>>` I/O operators), but it would add some complexity to the language.  Inertia is hard to overcome sometimes.

Comment: It is actually possible to statically typecheck printf but you need to have a language with a type system that supports dependent types. See [Cayenne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayenne_(programming_language)), for example.

Comment: I don't think being statically typed has anything to do with it.  C# is statically typed too, but keeps the type information in the assembly metadata.  Maybe just say the C type information is lost during compilation.

Comment: This is a fantastic explanation.

Comment: Excellent answer - just this one bit is misleading: "the bit pattern corresponding to the constant 'H' will be interpreted as a floating-point value". It's not the bit pattern, it's the numerical value: since character literals are *integers* in C, `'H'` is a number (an implementation-defined one). Then that number is converted according to the rules called the "**usual arithmetic conversions**". So on a typical ASCII system `'H'` is 72 and `float b = 'H'` is the bit pattern of the float value `72.0`.

Comment: @user106313 The answer to your question: "why doesn't the compiler write the format specifier by itself" is that modern compilers could, but that complexity wasn't worth it for the purposes C was originally made for. We usually think of `printf` as part of the language, it actually isn't - it's part of what has become the "standard library", but `printf` was originally designed as a *technically separate* thing - to the C language itself, and to most C compilers, `printf` wasn't (and still isn't) special: it's treated like any and all other functions defined by external libraries.

Answer (score 8):

Because at the moment when `printf` is called and does its job, the compiler is no longer there to tell it what to do.

The function doesn't get any information except what's in its parameters, and the vararg parameters don't have any type, so `printf` would have no clue how to print any if them if it didn't get explicit instructions via the format string. The compiler could (usually) deduce what type each argument is, but you would still have to write  format string to tell it *where* to print each argument relative to the constant text. Compare `"$%d"` and `"%d$"`; they do different things, and the compiler can't guess which you want. Since you have to compose a format string manually anyway to specify argument *positions*, it's an obvious choice to offload the task of stating the argument *types* to the user as well.

The alternative would be for the compiler to scan the format string for positions, then deduce the types, rewrite the format string to add the type information, and then compile the changed string into your binary instead. But that would only work for *literal* format strings; C also allows dynamically assigned format strings, and there would always be cases where the compiler can't accurately reconstruct what the format string is going to be at run-time. (Also, sometimes you want to print something as a different, related type, effectively performing a narrowing cast; that is also something that no compiler can predict.)

Comment: So, the printf() function knows that "x" is a variable but it doesn't know what is its type, yet the compiler knows. Can't we update printf() so that it could know the type of data. Moreover I recall that in C++ "cout" can print a data by automatically knowing its type.

Comment: @user31782 C function calls are extremely simple. All that `printf()` gets passed is a pointer to the format string and a pointer to the buffer where the arguments can be found. Not even the length of this buffer is passed! This is one of the reasons C can be so much faster than other languages. What you're proposing is orders of magnitude more complex.

Comment: @grahamparks Is "cout" in C++ slower than "printf". Would making printf() like "cout" make it slow?

Comment: @user31782: not necessarily slower at runtime (it depends, as usual), but it requires language features that simply aren't there in C. C doesn't have function overloading, let alone the template mechanisms used for `cout` in C++.

Comment: @Mat  So there are some basic problems with the language itself, it lacks some features.

Comment: Yes, but you should remember that C harks from 1972. These features were only *invented* much later.

Comment: I am new to programming, now I guess I understand this. Thankyou to all of you for explaining.

Answer (score 5):

`printf()` is what's known as a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), which is one that accepts a variable number of arguments.

Variadic functions in C use a special prototype to tell the compiler that the list of arguments is of unknown length:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...);
```

Standard C provides a set of functions in `stdarg.h` that can be used to retrieve the arguments one at a time and cast them to a given type.  This means that variadic functions have to decide the type of each argument for themselves.  `printf()` makes this decision based on what's in the format string.

This is a gross oversimplification of how `printf()` actually works, but the process goes like this:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...) {

    /* Get ready to process arguments that follow 'format' */
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, format);

    /* Deep in the function, something that's dissected the
       format string has decided that the next argument is a
       string.  Grab the next argument, cast it to char * and
       write it to wherever it should go.
     */
    char *string = va_arg(ap, char *);
    write_string_to_output(string);

    /* Conclude processing of arguments */
    va_end(ap);
}
```

The same process happens for all of the types `printf()` is capable of converting.  You can see an example of this in the [source code](http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/~checkout~/src/lib/libc/stdio/vfprintf.c?rev=1.66&content-type=text/plain) for OpenBSD's implementation of `vfprintf()`, which is the function that underpins `printf()`.

Some C compilers are smart enough to spot calls to `printf()`, evaluate the format string if it's a constant and verify that the types of the rest of the arguments are compatible with the conversions specified.  This behavior is not required, which is why the standard still requires providing the type as part of the format string.  Before these kinds of checks were made, mismatches between the format string and the argument list simply produced bogus output.

In C++, `<<` is an operator, which makes uses of `cout` such as `cout << foo << bar` an [infix expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation) that can be evaluated for correctness at compile time and turned into code that casts the right-hand expressions into something `cout` can deal with.

Answer (score 3):

The designers of C wanted to make the *compiler* as simple as possible.  While it would have been possible to handle I/O in much the fashion of other languages, and require that the compiler automatically supply the I/O routine with information about the types of passed parameters, and while such an approach might in many cases have allowed for more efficient code than is possible with `printf`(*), defining things that way would have made the compiler more complicated.

In the earliest days of C, code which called a function neither knew nor cared what arguments it was expecting.  Each argument would push some number of words on the stack according to its type, and functions would expect to find different parameters in the topmost, second-to-top, etc. stack slot below the return address.  If a `printf` method could figure out where to find its arguments on the stack, there was no way for the compiler to treat it any differently from any other method.

In practice, the pattern of parameter passing envisioned by C is very seldom used anymore except when calling variadic functions like `printf`, and if `printf` had been defined as using special parameter-passing conventions [e.g. having the first parameter be a compiler-generated `const char*` containing auto-generated information about the types to be passed], compilers would have been able to generate better code for it (avoiding the need for integer and floating-point promotions among other things).]  Unfortunately, I perceive zero likelihood of any compiler adding features to have compilers report variable types to called code.

I find it curious that null pointers are considered the "billion-dollar mistake", given their utility, and given that they generally only cause severely bad behavior in languages which don't trap null pointer arithmetic and accesses.  I'd consider the harm caused by `printf` and zero-terminated strings to be much worse.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like you are passing variables to another function that you have defined. You normally tell the other function which type of data it should expect/receive. The same way with `printf()`. It is already defined in the `stdio.h` library and requires you to tell it which data it is receiving so that it can output it in the right format (as in your case `int`).